# NodeJS using FS and AsyncJS blocking the UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async.js

I'm using react, electron, nodejs, asyncjs redux and thunk.
I wrote the following code which is supposed to download a list of files and write it to disk. In my code when the user presses a button i call this actionCreator:

```
export function downloadList(pack) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { downloadManager } = getState();

    async.each(downloadManager.downloadQueue[pack].libs, async (url, callback) => {
      const filename = url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0];
      await downloadFile(url, `dl/${filename}`);
      callback();
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('A file failed to process');
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED,
          packName: pack
        });
      }
    });
  };
}

async function downloadFile(url, path) {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  const request = https.get(url, (response) => {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', () => {
      file.close();
    });
  }).on('error', (err) => { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(path); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
  });
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do but while it does that, it blocks the entire UI. I really can't understand why it's happening since if i use an

```
setTimeout
```

with 3000ms delay inside the async.each it doesn't block the UI.
Another strange behaviour is that if i use the eachLimit function of asyncJS it just downloads me the limit of files, so if i want to download 100 files but i set eachLimit to 10 parallel, it just downloads the first 10 files and then stops. Can you enlight me about this?
I wanted to use axios to download files since it doesn't need to know if the urls are http or https but i can't find any resource on using axios with stream responsetype

Comment: try to after remove await from` await downloadFile(url, `dl/${filename}`);`

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first part. Pretty much every existent implementation of JavaScript runs on one thread. This means that the runtime is concurrent, but not parallel, i.e. the runtime does one and exactly one thing at a time. This means that if there is a function call that takes a while, it will block everything else. Therefore, something in the `downloadList` function is blocking the event loop. However, if you use `setTimeout`, then the `downloadList` function will be pushed onto the message queue, which will unblock the event and allow the UI to be rendered. For more information on the event loop check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)